# Is there any way to know whether a report has a subscription or not

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We have a SharePoint site and there are many reports, some of those reports with subscription and some without.

Currently, we need to go to Manage Subscription to see whether there is any subscription or not. Since we have so many reports, is there a easy way to tell whether a report has a subscription or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a report that could show me the status of all the report subscriptions.  Perhaps you can use this to get a complete list of reports and what subscriptions are associated with them.  I connect to my reporting services server.

```
SELECT    
  SubscriptionID, 
  SubscriptionOwner, 
  ModifiedDate, 
  Description, 
  EventType, 
  DeliveryExtension, 
  LastStatus, 
  LastRunTime,
  NextRunTime, 
  ScheduleName, 
  ReportPath, 
  ReportName, 
  ReportDescription
FROM    
  SubscriptionsList_v
```

I can't remember if  created this view or if it comes standard. here's the view I created

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    SUB.SubscriptionID,
    USR.UserName AS SubscriptionOwner,
    SUB.ModifiedDate, 
    SUB.Description,
    SUB.EventType,
    SUB.DeliveryExtension, 
    SUB.LastStatus, 
    SUB.LastRunTime,
    SCH.NextRunTime,
    SCH.Name AS ScheduleName,
    CAT.Path AS ReportPath, 
    REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(CAT.Path), CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(CAT.Path), 1) - 1)) AS ReportName, 
    CAT.Description AS ReportDescription
FROM  
    dbo.Subscriptions AS SUB INNER JOIN
    dbo.Users AS USR ON SUB.OwnerID = USR.UserID INNER JOIN
    dbo.Catalog AS CAT ON SUB.Report_OID = CAT.ItemID INNER JOIN
    dbo.ReportSchedule AS RS ON SUB.Report_OID = RS.ReportID AND SUB.SubscriptionID = RS.SubscriptionID INNER JOIN
     dbo.Schedule AS SCH ON RS.ScheduleID = SCH.ScheduleID
ORDER BY SubscriptionOwner, ReportPath
```

I'm pretty sure I didn't write this myself, but may have gotten it off the web somewhere.